# Can't download some apps from Google market after phone software update

Tags: applications, google-play-store

My phone is Sony Ericsson Xperia X10.

I just updated my phone's software to the latest Android version (2.3.3), however, I've found that I can't download some applications. It would start the download and within 5 seconds, I get a message (from my notification bar) informing me that the "download was unsucessful" I have tried downloading it several times after with the same result. Please advice!

Answer (score 4):

I would trying Force Closing and clearing the data for the Market in `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and rebooting your phone.